# Process description in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am writing a service in VB2010. Everything is working well, but when you look at the process in task manager, the description is: WindowsService1. I can't find where to change it. When I look at the project properties, the root namespace is WindowsService1, but if I change that it gives me an error: The string for the root namespace must be a valid identifier. I have looked at all the properties and can't find where to put a more descriptive description. It is not a show stopper, but I would like to be complete.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to rename your assembly name and its display name when the process is installed.

You can rename your assembly name from property pages of the application, as in the pic below:
[image: Assembly Name]

Secondly, when you write the installer for windows service, you can change the display name & description of the Windows Service, please refer the link below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller.description(v=vs.110).aspx